# Unable to get value from dropdown datalist JS/HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I have a basic dropdown list but I can't console the value when I select it(says undefined)

Tried .value, .text, .val() and they won't work. I have searched the web but I can't seem to find a solution.

Here's the HTML to it.

```
<datalist id="browsers">
          <option value="Pacients"></option>
          <option value="Doctor"></option>
</datalist>
```

JS code that i tried

```
console.log(document.getElementById('browsers').text);
console.log(document.getElementById('browsers').value);
console.log(document.getElementById('browsers').val());
```

After selection, i expect either 'Pacients' or 'Doctor' to be logged into the console, but gives me undefined instead or error for .val()

Comment: You should bind the datalist to a input box then you can get the value.You can refer [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_datalist.asp)

Answer (score 1):

If you want a dropdown use `<select>` and not `<datalist>`

The purpose of `<datalist>` is to be used as a list of suggestions on an autocomplete `<input>`. See https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_datalist.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using JQuery and accessing it like bellow:

```
$("#browsers option:selected").text()
```

Answer (score 0):

The element datalist must be within an input.

```
        <input id="browsers-input" list="browsers">
            <datalist id="browsers">
                  <option value="Pacients"></option>
                  <option value="Doctor"></option>
            </datalist>

<script>
var browsers_input = document.getElementById("browsers-input");
browsers_input.onchange = function(){
    console.log(browsers_input.value);
    console.log(document.getElementById("browsers-input").value);
};
</script>
```